# Cygwin Emacs, Windows Everything and ^M

Tags: encoding, emacs, cygwin, locate, emacs-helm

Within a Cygwin Emacs, how is it possible to use Helm (and the fantastic `es` command-line tool from Everything) to locate files on Windows?

I've the thing running easily, except that there are ^M after every file name from the `es` output.

Adding

```
("es" undecided-dos . undecided-unix)
```

in `process-coding-system-alist` did not solve anything...

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to resolve the problem:

```
;; Strip `^M' characters.
(add-to-list 'process-coding-system-alist
             '("sh" . (undecided-dos . undecided-unix))) ; `es' process.
```